# Crypto JS Encryption Java decryption

Tags: javascript, java, encryption

In my javascript, I have the following code:

```
      var encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt("Message that I am trying to send !", k, { mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC, padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7, iv:i });
    console.log("Cipher Text");
console.log(encrypted.ciphertext.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64));
 //prints out: 1e9z0zjI9MGBLW6AdLE+BiVnv9R9lDAS+SmSkX/Ufx7zTHOVanpiwd4IC2XejJaq
    console.log("Key: " + k);
//prints out f7710e2bcf419dab
    console.log("Iv: " + i);
// prints out 42d39acea111ceb2
```

Here is my decryption code on the java side:

```
 import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
    import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
    import java.security.Key;
    import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
    import java.security.Security;
    import java.security.spec.AlgorithmParameterSpec;

    import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.BaseNCodec;
    import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.Cipher;
    import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
    import javax.crypto.KeyGenerator;
    import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
    import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
    import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
    import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String encrypted = "1e9z0zjI9MGBLW6AdLE+BiVnv9R9lDAS+SmSkX/Ufx7zTHOVanpiwd4IC2XejJaq";
             SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec("f7710e2bcf419dab".getBytes("UTf-8"), "AES");
                AlgorithmParameterSpec iv = new IvParameterSpec("42d39acea111ceb2".getBytes("UTf-8"));
                byte[] decodeBase64 = Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted);

                Cipher cipher = null;
                try {
                    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
                } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                try {
                    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, iv);
                } catch (InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

              try {
                 String s = new String(cipher.doFinal(decodeBase64).toString());
                System.out.println(s);
            } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

When I decrypt on the java side, it throws an execption "**javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded**" Right away, my initial observation is that my padding on the encryption side is Pkcs7 while my padding on java is PKCS5Padding. I have been searching around the internet, the padding seems to be interchangeable? Could someone kindly explain what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: Not sure if that's your problem, but using `String.getBytes` whithout specifying a `Charset` is highly discouraged as this will be using your JVM's default character set that may vary from one machine to another. Try `String.getBytes("UTF-8")` instead.

Comment: Good point. I have updated the code to your UTF-8 suggestion, re-ran it and still the same `"javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded"'` I'll update the code in my question so it reflects the UTF-8.

Comment: It's your CryptoJS code that is causing this issue. The ciohertext output is incorrect. Include your key and IV in the question. They are in Hex encoding but use the actual byte values of the hex characters as the key, which is confusing.  Please clarify

Comment: Apologize if that came off confusing. I have included both the key and iv in the question. It's commented right under the console.log output. It sounds like your ask is how am I generating the key and IV. Right?

Comment: Check diff `AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding` and `padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7`